# Why Scala needs duplicate constructor? (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException)

Tags: scala, hadoop

I was receiving this error in my Hadoop job.
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <PackageName>.<ClassName>.<init>(<parameters>)`
In most Scala code, you would have it in compile time. But since this job is called in runtime I was not catching it in compile time.

I would think default parameter would cause constructors with both signatures to be created, one taking a single argument.

```
class BasicDynamicBlocker(args: Args, evaluation: Boolean = false) extends    Job(args) with HiveAccess {
//I NEEDED THIS TOO:
 def this(args: Args) = {
   this(args, false)
 }
```

...
   }

I learned the hard way that I needed to declare the overloaded constructor using `this`. (I wanted to write this out in case it helps someone else.) 
I also have a small questions. It still seems redundant to me. Is there a reason Scala language's design restrictions require this?

Comment: A good question is: How do you call the Constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not like when you have default parameter you will get overloads generated for each possible case, like for example:

```
def method(num: Int = 4, str: String = "") = ???
```

you expect compiler to generate

```
def method(num: Int) = method(num, "")
def method(str: String) = method(4, str)
def method() = method(4, "")
```

but that is not the case.

You will instead have generated methods (in companion object), for each default param

```
def method$default$1: Int = 4
def method$default$2: String = "a"
```

and whenever you say in your code

```
method(str = "a")
```

it will be just changed to

```
method(method$default$1, "a")
```

So in your case, constructor with signature `this(args: Args)` just did not exist, there was only the 2 param version.

You can read more here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/named-and-default-arguments.html