# class constructor with default value reflection

Tags: scala

Why is it that the following produces a `NoSuchMethodException`:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> class Test(val i: Int = 5)
defined class Test

scala> classOf[Test].getDeclaredConstructor()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Test.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
... 32 elided
```

Even though I can easily do:

```
scala> new Test()
res0: Test = Test@707f7052

scala> res0.i
res1: Int = 5
```

The javap is not very helpfull:

```
scala> :javap Test
  Size 579 bytes
  MD5 checksum 20263ec5d03959f8477847f3d71b324e
  Compiled from "<console>"
public class Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               Test
   #2 = Class              #1             // Test
   #3 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #4 = Class              #3             // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               <console>
   #6 = Utf8               i
   #7 = Utf8               I
   #8 = Utf8               ()I
   #9 = NameAndType        #6:#7          // i:I
  #10 = Fieldref           #2.#9          // Test.i:I
  #11 = Utf8               this
  #12 = Utf8               LTest;
  #13 = Utf8               <init>
  #14 = Utf8               (I)V
  #15 = Utf8               ()V
  #16 = NameAndType        #13:#15        // "<init>":()V
  #17 = Methodref          #4.#16         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #18 = Utf8               
  #19 = Class              #18            // 
  #20 = Utf8               $line6/$read
  #21 = Class              #20            // $line6/$read
  #22 = Utf8               
  #23 = Utf8               
  #24 = Class              #23            // 
  #25 = Utf8               Test
  #26 = Utf8               Code
  #27 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #28 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #29 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #30 = Utf8               InnerClasses
  #31 = Utf8               ScalaInlineInfo
  #32 = Utf8               Scala
{
  public int i();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #10                 // Field i:I
         4: ireturn
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LTest;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 11: 0

  public Test(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: iload_1
         2: putfield      #10                 // Field i:I
         5: aload_0
         6: invokespecial #17                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         9: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0  this   LTest;
            0      10     1     i   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 11: 0
        line 14: 5
}
SourceFile: "<console>"
InnerClasses:
     public static #22= #19 of #21; //=class  of class $line6/$read
     public static #22= #24 of #19; //=class  of class 
     public static #25= #2 of #24; //Test=class Test of class 
Error: unknown attribute
  ScalaInlineInfo: length = 0xE
   01 00 00 02 00 0D 00 0E 00 00 06 00 08 00
Error: unknown attribute
  Scala: length = 0x0
```

It seems there is only one constructor which takes an int.
I suspect the magic scala is performing is hidden away in one of the InnerClasses but I don't know how to inspect them.

PS: if the field `i` is not declared with `val` the getDeclaredConstructor() output is the same.

Comment: see my answer to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/37192335/5123895

Comment: I thought I had done a proper search before posting :(